# Is there any insight to Harry Potter's wealth after the first movie?

Tags: harry-potter

**TLDR**

- Is [this](https://www.buzzfeed.com/andyneuenschwander/harry-potter-was-rich-af?utm_term=.bvq9l6OmBn#.kwBVNGRjQE) the best indication of Harry's wealth according to our/wizard standards?
- Is his wealth ever mentioned again after the first book?

I missed the first movie in the Harry Potter marathon running today, but if I remember right the book and the film both had a scene where Harry Potter is confirmed to be "wealthy."

I found this [link](http://www.businessinsider.com/how-harry-potter-got-rich-2015-9) while trying to see how rich he is. Within it makes it sound as though the business connections were routinely sold off until Harry's father inherited a Scrooge McDuck bank pile of money and left it to Harry upon his death.

According to [this](https://www.buzzfeed.com/andyneuenschwander/harry-potter-was-rich-af?utm_term=.bvq9l6OmBn#.kwBVNGRjQE) (same link as above) Harry's wealth may not be "that" much, though it does not calculate all the pieces or the assets in his name either. Is there any better indication other than this link?

Comment: Having to vote to close this as too broad, which is a shame since it's a decent question. Having supplementary questions to help clarify what you're asking is fine but you have three seperate (if connected) questions. I'd suggest narrowing your question to the one about his net worth after the first movie/the Buzzfeed article. What he does with his wealth, for instance, would count as a seperate question.

Comment: @TheDarkLord How about this?

Comment: Better. I don't think it's closeworthy now. I'd just give a friendly reminder that the more specific your question is the more likely it is that you'll get good answers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Harry's wealth is mentioned extensively throughout the book series and at least once (and usually several times) in each book.

**HP and the Chamber of Secrets**

> Harry said nothing. He felt a bit awkward. **Stored in an underground
>   vault at Gringotts in London was a small fortune that his parents had
>   left him.** Of course, it was only in the wizarding world that he had
>   money; you couldn’t use Galleons, Sickles and Knuts in Muggle shops.
>   He had never mentioned his Gringotts bank account to the Dursleys; he
>   didn’t think their horror of anything connected with magic would
>   stretch to a large pile of gold.

and

> Harry felt even worse when they reached his vault. **He tried to block
>   the contents from view as he hastily shoved handfuls of coins into a
>   leather bag.**

**HP and the Prison of Azkaban**

> Once Harry had refilled his money bag with gold Galleons, silver
>   Sickles and bronze Knuts from his vault at Gringotts, he needed to
>   exercise a lot of self-control not to spend the whole lot at once. **He
>   had to keep reminding himself that he had five years to go at
>   Hogwarts, and how it would feel to ask the Dursleys for money for
>   spellbooks, to stop himself buying a handsome set of solid gold
>   Gobstones** (a wizarding game rather like marbles, in which the stones
>   squirted a nasty-smelling liquid into the other player’s face when
>   they lost a point).

**HP and the Goblet of Fire**

> ‘The gold I gave you at the Quidditch World Cup,’ said Ron. **‘The leprechaun gold I gave you for my Omnioculars. In the Top Box. Why didn’t you tell me it disappeared?’**
>   Harry had to think for a moment before he realised what Ron was talking about.
>   ‘Oh …’ he said, the memory coming back to him at last. **‘I dunno … I never noticed it had gone**. I was more worried about my wand, wasn’t I?’
>   They climbed the steps into the Entrance Hall and went into the Great Hall for lunch.
>   **‘Must be nice,’ Ron said abruptly, when they had sat down and started serving themselves roast beef and Yorkshire puddings. ‘To have so much money you don’t notice if a pocketful of Galleons goes missing.’**

**HP and the Order of the Phoenix**

> Harry grinned. **He had forced the Weasley twins to take the thousand
>   Galleons prize money he had won in the Triwizard Tournament to help
>   them realise their ambition to open a joke shop,** but he was still glad
>   to know that his part in furthering their plans was unknown to Mrs
>   Weasley. She did not think running a joke shop was a suitable career
>   for two of her sons.

**Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince**

> **Bill,** who would be staying at home with Fleur (much to Hermione and Ginny’s pleasure), **passed a full money-bag across the table to Harry.**
>   ‘Where’s mine?’ demanded Ron at once, his eyes wide.
>   **‘That’s already Harry’s, idiot,’** said Bill. ‘I got it out of your vault for you, Harry, because it’s taking about five hours for the public to get to their gold at the moment, the goblins have tightened security so much. Two days ago Arkie Philpott had a Probity Probe stuck up his … well, trust me, this way’s easier.’
>   ‘Thanks, Bill,’ said Harry, pocketing his gold.

**Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows**

> **Gringotts had seemed a place of wonder that day, the enchanted
>   repository of a trove of gold he had never known he possessed,** and
>   never for an instant could he have dreamed that he would return to
>   steal … But within seconds they were standing in the vast marble hall
>   of the bank.

Comment: He is still rich. Thank you. I was mostly curious why he kept having things given to him for free in the movies and never went back to the bank. Books, brooms, etc. I was thinking he had gone broke somehow...

Comment: @Odin1806 Honestly though, I feel like people seem to get more free stuff if they are rich than if they are broke.

Comment: @martin -  You'd like this film; http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0046072/

Comment: @Valorum thanks for the recommendation. I'll try to track it down.